# react-native-select-list undefined is not an object(evaluaton "items.props.value")

Tags: react-native, select

can somebody tell me what is wrong with this code? It renders without any issue but when I select an option from the list I am getting undefined is not an object (evaluating "items.props.value") error

```
                  <Select
                    ref="selectCountry"
                    default={this.state.country}
                    onSelect={(ctr) => this.setState({ country: ctr })}
                    selectStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#e7e7e7', width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2, alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 15 }}
                    selectTextStyle={{ color: "#1f1f1f", fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro Regular', textAlign: 'center', paddingLeft: 15 }}
                    caret={<Image style={{ flex: 1, height: 12, width: 55, resizeMode: 'contain', marginTop: 5 }} source={require('../../../assets/img/search_result/arrow_drop.png')} />}
                  >
                    <Option value="country" optionTextStyle={{ fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular', color: "black" }} color="black">country</Option>

                    {this.state.filters && this.state.filters.country && Array.isArray(this.state.filters.country) == true ? this.state.filters.country.map(name => {

                      return <Option value={name} optionTextStyle={{ fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular', color: "black" }} color="black">{name}</Option>

                    }) : (this.state.filters && this.state.filters.country ? <Option value={this.state.filters.country} optionTextStyle={{ fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular', color: "black" }} color="black"> {this.state.filters.country}</Option> : <Option value="country" optionTextStyle={{ fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular', color: "black" }} color="black">country</Option>)}

                  </Select>
```